# What are reasons to choose between explicit midpoint method and improved Euler method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

What are the reason's to choose between the explicit midpoint method and the improved Euler method in solving an ordinary differential equation numerically?

Explicit midpoint method: $y_{i+1} = y_i + h f\left( x_i + \frac h 2, y_i + \frac h 2 f(x_i,y_i) \right)$

Improved Euler method: $y_{i+1} = y_i + \frac h 2 f\left( x_i, y_i \right) + \frac h 2 f\left( x_{i+1}, y_i + h f(x_i,y_i) \right)$

Both methods are of second order, so there should not be much difference in theory. What else can be said about these approaches?

Comment: You don't, you use a higher order method where you have the same question in choosing variants of the DoPri45 method etc. Practically you will see more uses of the Heun method (impr. Euler), for instance in the time direction of the Crank-Nicholson scheme.

Comment: When you do the error analysis for a general explicit two-stage Runge-Kutta method of order 2, then you can ask for the constant in front of the $h^3$ term in the Taylor series expansion of the local error. This constant will be different for different methods, see p. ex. [A. Ralston, Math. Comput. 16 (80), 431–437, 1962].